# HAProxy - health check sub directories/service

Tags: haproxy

I have a server that host multiple sites but logically looks like sub directories. Example:

```
 - http://XXX/Site1
 - http://XXX/Site2
```

How do I configure HAProxy's health check to check each "sub site"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple backends, each checking 1 site. Use ACLs to perform content switching, i.e. selecting the backend to route the request to based on some property of the HTTP request, in this case the URL path.

Example:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    maxconn 4096
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend 1.2.3.4-80
    bind 1.2.3.4:80
    mode http
    option http-server-close
    option logasap

    acl url_site1 url_beg /Site1
    acl url_site2 url_beg /Site2

    use_backend site1 if url_site1
    use_backend site2 if url_site2


backend site1
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk HEAD /Site1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ XXX
    server srv1 1.1.1.1:80 check
    server srv2 2.2.2.2:80 check

backend site2
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk HEAD /Site2 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ XXX
    server srv1 1.1.1.1:80 check
    server srv2 2.2.2.2:80 check
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable HTTP check in Haproxy to check HTTP Servers

```
  https://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/httpchk

    backend cluster1
    mode http
        balance roundrobin
    option  httplog
    option httpclose        #Disable keepalive
    option  forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0

    backend cluster2
    mode http
        balance roundrobin
    option  httplog
    option httpclose        #Disable keepalive
    option  forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
        # Servers
```

Comment: How do I do it for each sub site